# user friendly framework for personal website?

Tags: php, python, frameworks

Hi,
Which are the user friendly frameworks for building personal sites? Specially if that comes with little programming knowledge. And integrated jquery will be great. python or php based framework will do better.

I tried wordpress and joomla! But those are far more complex for a simple personal site with personal blogging, live commenting, twitting, keeping personal projects and resume etc.

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd better ask this question on stackoverflow.com - it is programming issue.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a simple personal site with personal blogging, live commenting, twitting, keeping personal projects and resume etc."

In my opinion, a personal site means a single author.  You don't have a lot of really "dynamic" content.  How many times a day will  you update a person site?  Once?  Twice?

A blog, comment, twitter things change relatively slowly -- once or twice a day.

Personal projects, resume, etc. change even more slowly.

None of this *requires* dynamic content creation.  A database is often more trouble than help.  Most of it is simply unstructured text.  Consequently, consider using a toolset to build static HTML and simply FTP that to a server.

Consider using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to build static content.  You can generate a mountain of content, maintain it, and upload it periodically.  You don't need to know HTML because you write in RST.  It's easy to generate hundreds of pages of content and adjust the look and feel.

Best of all, it's very, very lightweight.  You can easily get by with zero code.  Or, if you want to add directives or interpreted text roles, you can do a little coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I have created a wrong concept (I am sorry). I myself am a programmer (java and python) and I don't want to waste much time after creating and updating personal site. And joomla! or wordpress are complex in a sense that "firing cannon to kill a mosquito". I wanted a light weight simple framework/CMS to manage a personal site. I will try Sphinx...

Answer (score 2):

"I tried wordpress and joomla! But those are far more complex for a simple personal site with personal blogging, live commenting, twitting, keeping personal projects and resume etc."

Nothing can be simpler to your needs than wordpress. You can use it to create not only posts to your blog but what they call "static pages", like a "contact" page, a "resume" and such. You edit this page like a "microsoft word" box in the admin panel. You don't even need to edit a php file, you dont need to create a layout, just download a free template (search google for this).

Wordpress can be installed in a variety of plataforms since it doesn't need a lot of requirements. It's PHP, its easier to find a cheap hosting (even a machine in your own home): see their [requirements page](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) for yourself.

The only thing you may need "out of the box" is the twitting thing, that you can achieve by downloading some plugins from their official website.

If you find that to achieve your goals using wordpress is too complicated, I don't think it's a good idea to use a "framework", **unless you want to learn coding**. You can achieve what you need in wordpress without coding a single line.

Oh, and it has jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Personal Web Site Starter Kit (http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/personal), very easy to install and maintain and it's got what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a free CMS system?

I could suggest you several good .NET CMS which are either open sorce or commercial but have a limited free editions very well suited for perosnal sites

[Kentico](http://www.kentico.com/free-cms-asp-net.aspx) - really simple thing, that you can use without any programming knwoledge, easy to setup, but free edition is limited with 1 blog only. so only for personal use, nothing more, or you will need to buy a commercial edition...

[Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) - open source, but will require knowledge of XSL templates if you want to build really good site. not easy to learn if you are not a developer

[Sitefinity](http://www.telerik.com/products/sitefinity.aspx) - commercial CMS from Telerik but they have a community edition. Worth looking at. I suppose the complexity of learning somewhere between Kentico and Umbraco. But simple web sites will not require development

In any case I recomend you a great resource [CMSMatrix.org](http://cmsmatrix.org) where you can compare more then 100 CMS on different platforms and languages.

p.s.

And if you just want a simple personal web site and don't want to care about hosting, databases etc. I suppose you could look at [Google Sites](http://www.google.com/sites/help/intl/en/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

for PHP ones, beside joomla that you've already mentioned, I can suggest :

**Drupal** (http://drupal.org/).

Or a much simpler one :

**Dotclear** (http://dotclear.org/)

Answer (score 0):

AnchorCMS gets a lot of good feedback, give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Plone](http://www.plone.org/). Perhaps this meets your requirements.

Comment: If Morison finds Joomla too complex, I wonder whether Plone will be a good match...

Comment: Yes, Plone is definitely not one of the easier ones.

Answer (score -1):

Kentico,Umbraco and Sitefinity,DotNetNuke  are meant for developers/designers/integrators. Use Wordpress or if you are looking for .NET version use Community server.

Comment: does Community server free edition exists? perhaps I'm wrong, but I heard that now Community server is a very expensive thing. It is so expensive that Telligent even regret to show the price of it on its web site :) With DotNetNuke I will agree - if you are not developer it is not your choise. But with Kentico, I was able to create a small web site for a non-profit organization without writing a line of code.